# Using external drive for scheduled backups and file history with encryption

Tags: encryption

I want to use an external drive for scheduled backups and file history for Windows 10 with encryption, when I disconnect the drive from the computer I want it to automatically be locked and If the user is changed on the computer I do not want the other users to be able to see the data on the hard drive.

Is there a method that you know of, or can someone help me write a .bat file to do something like this?

I have already tried file permissions and I can't get that to work for external hard drives.

Comment: My answer to this question is in the comments in the link: https://superuser.com/questions/1362591/how-to-encrypt-file-history-backup-files?noredirect=1#comment2051106_1362591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding it is possible to use bitlocker, but it is only available on the Windows 10 professional edition of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure about:

- How the drive is being encrypted
- How you are "unlocking" the drive when you first mount it

From what I understand I would suggest using VeraCrypt. It is open-source and it is able to save a password to a particular computer only so it is easy to mount an encrypted container. I would also recommend setting up a key file as an additional layer of authentication so the drive cannot be decrypted on any other computer without it.

VeraCrypt also uses on-the-fly encryption, meaning data is only decrypted as needed, so if you disconnect the drive you don't have to worry about leaving things unencrypted.

Comment: The VeraCrypt software requires people to reformat the drive before the software works.Is there some other suggestions?

Comment: @SuperUserJL VeraCrypt doesn't require you to reformat the drive unless you want to. You should make an encrypted container on the drive, which acts like a normal file. When you unlock the file with VeraCrypt, it will create a separate virtual drive that is running off the original drive, keeping all the functionality of the original drive without having to reformat it. If you would like to read more about how to do this (really easy to understand), here's this from the official site: https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Beginner%27s%20Tutorial.html

Comment: VeraCrypt did require formatting a drive. It might have been a good if a person has the time to wait for formatting, it was going to take 10 hours to format the external hard drive. I don't want to wait 10 hours for it to format and I would have to move files that were on the hard drive to a different storage location which would take more time, and back which would take more time.

Comment: @SuperUserJL As I said, create an encrypted container at a desirable size on the drive and add to it as necessary. DO NOT reformat the whole drive with the drive encryption feature. In my experience it has been a little difficult to set up anyway. Please know any full-disk encryption program will require a reformat or equivalent since it still needs encrypt the existing files, and it doesn't do it magically. If you are concerned about speed, pick the fastest cipher at setup (like AES, no combinations). Plan B would also be to not use a cheap drive with slow read/write speeds. Get an SSD.